# How to reload a UItableView with rows and section

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, rows, sections

I have a UITableView displaying a list of plants in alphabetical sections. Within the app, the user can change the language. When the language is changed, the method:

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

now displays the same plants in a new language. The problem is that the rows and sections are intact, and still sorted in the alphabetical order of the previous language. I have googled and read up and down stackoverflow to find a solution. The closest I came was:

```
[[self tableView]reloadData];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]);
NSIndexSet *sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Still, I have to run the tableView through `viewdDidLoad` to change the alphabetical sorting.

What is the best way to force a new alphabetial sorting after `[[self tableview]reloadData];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `reloadData` you first need to update all of your data used by the table view data source and delegate methods.

You do not need to call `viewDidLoad` again. Put the code to setup the data structures in its own method. Then you can call this setup method from `viewDidLoad` (if needed) as well as just before calling `reloadData` after a language change.